# Should I use wtforms with Pylons?

Tags: django, validation, forms, pylons, wtforms

I am migrating my django project to pylons and am up to form validations.
Is the builtin formencode module sufficient for form validation or is WTforms a "better" option? What would be the advatanges of using wtforms?

I chose sqlalchemy as the orm backend so something that plays nicely with that would be nice too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WTForms is very similar to django forms. If you are *migrating* you should probably use it to speedup your migration.

Answer (score 3):

I also recommend WTForms it's much easier to use than formencode and have builtin sqlalchemy extensions.